# MySQL: Store multiple commas separated strings into temp table

Tags: mysql, sql, split

Given String

```
string 1: 'A,B,C,D,E'
string 2: 'X091,X089,X051,X043,X023'
```

Want to store into the temp table as:

```
String1     String2
---------------------
A           X091
B           X089
C           X051
D           X043
E           X023
```

Tried: SQL server version on the code on Stack overflow.
The below code works on SQL server. **But I want the mysql version of it.  Please help...**

```
DECLARE @str1 VARCHAR(1000)= 'A,B,C,D,E';
DECLARE @str2 VARCHAR(1000)= 'X091,X089,X051,X043,X023';

;WITH
 --split the first string
 a1 AS (SELECT n=0, i=-1, j=0 UNION ALL SELECT n+1, j, CHARINDEX(',', @str1, j+1) FROM a1 WHERE j > i)
,b1 AS (SELECT n, SUBSTRING(@str1, i+1, IIF(j>0, j, LEN(@str1)+1)-i-1) s FROM a1 WHERE i >= 0)
 --split the second string
,a2 AS (SELECT n=0, i=-1, j=0 UNION ALL SELECT n+1, j, CHARINDEX(',', @str2, j+1) FROM a2 WHERE j > i)
,b2 AS (SELECT n, SUBSTRING(@str2, i+1, IIF(j>0, j, LEN(@str2)+1)-i-1) s FROM a2 WHERE i >= 0)
--join them by the index
SELECT b1.n
      ,b1.s AS s1
      ,b2.s AS s2
FROM b1
INNER JOIN b2 ON b1.n=b2.n
ORDER BY b1.n;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive `cte` to split the strings, and then join the results together:

```
with recursive cte(id, c, s, r) as (
   select t.id, 0, regexp_substr(t.str, '^[^,]+'), regexp_replace(t.str, '^[^,]+,*', '') 
   from tbl t
   union all
   select c.id, c.c + 1, regexp_substr(c.r, '^[^,]+'), regexp_replace(c.r, '^[^,]+,*', '') 
   from cte c where length(c.r) > 0
)
select c1.s, c2.s from cte c1 join cte c2 on c2.c = c1.c where c1.id = 1 and c2.id = 2
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-a2WSo7l).